link cobordism classes
Just an extremely basic question on link cobordism:
It would seem that all (framed) 1-links in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are (framed) cobordant to (framed) unlinks  and in fact: to (framed) unknots --- for instance by appeal to the Pontryagin isomorphism (incidentally considered in Math:SE:q/426482) or more explicitly by application of the following kind of "fusion"/"saddle" moves to all crossings of a given link diagram:

And yet there seems to be literature on non-trivial link cobordism classes (e.g. Kawauchi 1980) --- what is it that evades the above conclusion?

My first guess is that when people talk about cobordism a cobordism from L to L', they think about pairwise disjoint cobordisms from one component of L to one of L'.

The variety of "cobordism" you use often depends on your application.  Sometimes the components of the links are labelled and/or maybe framed, etc.

MarcoGolla, @RyanBudney thanks, I see now that early authors like Hosokawa (1967) https://doi.org/10.2307/1970693 or Cappell & Shaneson (1980) https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/link.pdf require their link cobordisms to be cylindrical, hence to be concordances, rather, which would explain the issue. But it is confusing: More recent authors, especially in Khovanov homology (starting with Khovanov https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9908171 Sec 6.3) don't mean this restriction when they speak of "link cobordism", cf. Lobb (2024) Fig 11 https://www.ams.org/notices/202405/rnoti-p621.pdf .

Correct.  Devoid of additional context words like "homology" and "cobordism" are often just a descriptor of a family of ideas rather than something specific, at least in geometric topology, manifold theory, knot theory, etc.  Usually there is a default understanding for what the term should mean, but once you get to any fairly specific area those assumptions tend to melt away.

It looks like early authors actually mean "link concordance" when saying "link cobordism", i.e. considering only cylindrical cobordisms: e.g. Hosokawa (1967) [doi.org/10.2307/1970693] or Cappell & Shaneson (1980) [pdf]. If that's the definition that Kawauchi (1980) [doi:10.1016/0040-9383(80)90017-8] means to be using it would explain his result.
But other (later) authors say "link cobordism" for actual (not necessarily cylindrical) cobordisms between links, especially in Khovanov homology (possibly starting with Khovanov (2000) Sec 6.3  [arXiv:math/9908171]), cf. Lobb (2024) Fig 11 [pdf]. Accordingly, these authors are not interested in link cobordism classes (which now are all trivial in the unframed case), but in characterizing the cobordisms themselves.
Though explicit comments to this effect I have not seen in the literature.

In a sense this issue goes back to the beginning of topology.  In Poincare's first draft of Analysis Situs, he used the term "homology" as a synonym for what we now call "singular oriented bordism".  It was only when he started seeing problems in the proof of Poincare duality that he switched to simplicial homology.

@RyanBudney sure, I suspected there was some undeclared fine-print implicit in Kawauchi's article, but the question was: "what is it?" :-) I feel it's a worthwhile question and I believe the above is the answer.
